# Query Athena tables & output column for 'S3 source' path

Tags: amazon-athena

Currently using information_schema.tables to list all tables in my catalog.
What I am missing, is a column to tell me which S3 path each table (external) is pointing to.

Looked in all the information_schema tables, but cannot see this info.
The only place I've seen this via 'sql' is with the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' command, which doesn't give the result in a proper recordset.

Failing that ... is there another way to keep tabs on all of your tables and their sources ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is table location. Note that for partitioned table, each partition has separate location, which may or may not be under table's location.

Comment: Good point. For my purposes, would it help to say that I am after the bucket that was crawled? I'm trying to compare my list of S3 buckets against list of tables, and visualize the relationships between them. So far I have no way to see which S3 buckets are 'feeding' which tables.

Comment: I think you need to do this programmatically on the client side. I don't think there is a SQL query that would pull this information for many tables as once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as above, could find no way of doing this from the database.

Actual solution below for interest (& in case anyone finds a better way)

From CLI:
Call AWS glue get-tables & output json to file
Sync file to S3
ETL job to convert multi-line json into single-line json and place in new bucket
Crawl new bucket
Now query/unnest in Athena

'convoluted' is a word that comes to mind !
At least it gets there data I need where I need it 
Again, if anyone finds an easier way.... ?